# How to use debian command on python os have error expected 2 arguments got 1

Tags: python-3.x

I want to use command wakeonlan XX:XX:XX:XX:XX in python how i can do these?

Now I try
os.write(XX:XX:XX:XX:XX) but i have error expected 2 arguments got 1

Comment: `os.system`, `subprocess.run`, `subprocess.Popen`

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
#windows:
subprocess.run("wakeonlan -w -mac XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", shell=True) 
#ubuntu
subprocess.run("wakeonlan XX:XX:XX:XX:XX", shell=True)
```

I am not sure if you need admin privileges or not, if you do then you need to open python script with privileges.
when you do that whole program will be granted with allong with all opened subprocesses and opened files.
So be cerfull.